# Matlab print figure to eps consistently cuts of the axis labels

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to make Matlab, 7.10.0.499 (R2010a), write out a figure to eps using `print` but it keeps cropping of the axis labels no matter what paper size I set the figure to, unless I make it an A3.

This a png to illustrate the problem (although I understand that png's come out of a different render pipeline).

[image]

The code to produce this graph is:

```
    figure, 
set(gcf, 'renderer', 'painters');

loglog(p_m_tt, p_fa_tt, 'k-', 'LineWidth', 2); hold on;
loglog(p_m_oo, p_fa_oo, 'k--', 'LineWidth', 2); hold on;
loglog(p_m_ot, p_fa_ot, 'k-.', 'LineWidth', 3); hold on;
fontSize = 9;

l = legend('Cam1-Cam1', 'Cam2-Cam2', 'Cam2-Cam1', ...
    'Location', 'NorthEast');

fontSize = 20;
xlabel('$P_{fa}$', 'fontsize', fontSize);
ylabel('$P_{m}$', 'fontsize', fontSize);

set(gca, 'XMinorTick', 'off', 'YMinorTick', 'off', 'YGrid', 'on', 'XGrid', 'on');
set(gcf, 'PaperPositionMode', 'auto');
set(gca, 'XTick', [0.00001 0.0001 0.001 0.01 0.1 1]);
set(gca, 'MinorGridLineStyle', 'none');

set(gca, 'FontSize', fontSize);
set(gcf, 'defaultAxesFontName', 'Times New Roman');

axis square;

X = 13;
Y = 13;
xMargin = 0.25;             %# left/right margins from page borders
yMargin = 0.25;             %# bottom/top margins from page borders
xSize = X - 2*xMargin;      %# figure size on paper (widht & height)
ySize = Y - 2*yMargin; 

set(gcf, 'PaperUnits', 'centimeters');
set(gcf, 'PaperSize', [X Y]);
set(gcf, 'PaperPosition', [0 0 xSize ySize]);
print('-depsc2', f);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-loose` option with print so that matlab doesn't crop it. See the helpfile on print for details.

Comment: This answer is actually probably the best. It stopped my figures from getting cropped. I had to then go edit them in inkscape, but at least they aren't cuttoff.

Answer (score 1):

I took your code and ran it (replacing the variables to plot for dummy data, of course) and the loaded the eps in illustrator, and it came out just fine. Which version of matlab are you using?

Also, just in case, I did modify the code just a little, as it wouldn't run before because the variable "f" was not defined, I'm including the code and an example of what I got:

```
f=figure;
set(gcf, 'renderer', 'painters'); 

p_m_tt=10e-4*0:0.001:1;
p_m_oo=p_m_tt;
p_m_ot=p_m_oo;
p_fa_tt=rand(size(p_m_tt));
p_fa_oo=rand(size(p_m_tt));
p_fa_ot=rand(size(p_m_tt));
loglog(p_m_tt, p_fa_tt, 'k-', 'LineWidth', 2); hold on; 
loglog(p_m_oo, p_fa_oo, 'k--', 'LineWidth', 2); hold on; 
loglog(p_m_ot, p_fa_ot, 'k-.', 'LineWidth', 3); hold on; 

l = legend('Cam1-Cam1', 'Cam2-Cam2', 'Cam2-Cam1', ... 
    'Location', 'NorthEast'); 

fontSize = 20; 
xlabel('$P_{fa}$', 'fontsize', fontSize); 
ylabel('$P_{m}$', 'fontsize', fontSize); 

set(gca, 'XMinorTick', 'off', 'YMinorTick', 'off', 'YGrid', 'on', 'XGrid', 'on'); 
set(gcf, 'PaperPositionMode', 'auto'); 
set(gca, 'XTick', [0.00001 0.0001 0.001 0.01 0.1 1]); 
set(gca, 'MinorGridLineStyle', 'none'); 

set(gca, 'FontSize', fontSize); 
set(gcf, 'defaultAxesFontName', 'Times New Roman'); 

axis square; 

X = 13; 
Y = 13; 
xMargin = 0.25;             %# left/right margins from page borders 
yMargin = 0.25;             %# bottom/top margins from page borders 
xSize = X - 2*xMargin;      %# figure size on paper (widht & height) 
ySize = Y - 2*yMargin;  

set(gcf, 'PaperUnits', 'centimeters'); 
set(gcf, 'PaperSize', [X Y]); 
set(gcf, 'PaperPosition', [0 0 xSize ySize]); 
print('-depsc2', f,'figure2.eps');
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I am running 7.10.0.499 (R2010a) and this baffles me.

Comment: I tried all the above in 7.14.0.739 (R2012a 64-bit), maybe you could try getting the "y label" closer to the plot by modifying it's 'Position' atribute.

Comment: Doesn't work I am afraid, something is adjusting the cropping border every time in such a manner that it keeps slicing of part of the labels.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of modifying the figure `PaperPosition` one can also modify the axis `position` property. The current setting can be retrieved by:

```
get(gca, 'position')
```

ans =

```
0.1300    0.1300    0.7750    0.7750
```

These codify for `[left bottom width height]`. Then increase the margins by increasing the first two numbers and decreasing the latter two:

```
set(gca, 'position', [.15, .15, .74, .74]);
```